# jQuery Timepicker UseSelect

Tags: jquery, html

Not sure what's happening here although when using jQuery Timepicker found [here](https://timepicker.co/options/)

I choose the useSelect option to make the input field act like a dropdown and I'm struggling to get the database value into the select box.

HTML:

```
      echo "<td><center style='border-bottom: 1px solid; border-color: $color_5;'><input style='text-align:center;' type='text' class='some-time-inputs' value='$lstr_sd_start' name='start_status'></td>";
      echo "<td><center style='border-bottom: 1px solid; border-color: $color_6;'><input style='text-align:center;' type='text' class='some-time-inputs' value='$lstr_sd_end' name='end_status'></td>";>
```

JS:

```
$('.some-time-inputs').timepicker(   { 'timeFormat': 'H:i',
    'listWidth' : 1,
     'useSelect' : true,
    'step' : 5} );
```

The value is getting saved when I choose it in the dropdown list as I can see it on the inspect element when refreshing (the database is also updated)

[image]
[image]

Another picture here of the inspect with further information

[image]

Comment: are you able to select dropdown values? if yes what are the values of $lstr_sd_start and $lstr_sd_end

Comment: Hi @SandeepModak - Yes I can select dropdown values - the values of $lstr_sd_start is 00:10:00 and $lstr_sd_end is 01:00:00

Comment: center element has some dynamic style color $color_5  is it getting applied ?

Comment: your code seems has no issue otherwise check :-https://jsfiddle.net/jzw0dgqr/

Comment: The dynamic style colour is being applied correctly yep. And I just checked your fiddle, how strange... it's working as intended in the fiddle but not on my own environment hmm, the value just seems to be getting hidden on mine. Not sure what else to check!

Comment: what datatables  are you using?

Comment: I'm using the datatables from https://datatables.net/

Comment: try removing table id just for a check if datatables css causing any problem

Comment: I've removed the datatable and still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript to the following

```
$('.some-time-inputs').timepicker({ 
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    listWidth : 1,
    useSelect : true,
    interval: 5
});
```

Comment: Hi David thanks for the suggestion although no luck! I've added a further screenshot of the inspect element, perhaps that helps.

Comment: The only error I'm getting is - https://gyazo.com/88f8b33fd139840bd93975734658a94e

Not sure if that can cause it as I'm not using datetimepicker anywhere

Comment: I've fixed that error and now there's nothing being logged in the console